# Logout button to unset and destroy the SESSION variables not working

Tags: php, html, session, logout

I have a PHP page in which I have the button for login and register. But the problem in my page is that when I log out the button is not redirected to the php page of logout to unset and destroy the session variables.

I am providing here the code of that page so that someone can help me rectify the error.

```
<div class="wrapper row1">
<header id="header" class="clear"> 
    <!-- THE BANNER -->
    <div id="logo" class="fl_left"> 
        <a href="index.php"> <img src="images\logo.jpg"></a>            
    </div>
    <div class="fl_right">
        <ul class="inline">
            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +91 1234567890 </li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> info@hoteldaffodils.com </li>
            <?php   if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
            {
            ?>
            <li>
            <?php  
                echo $_SESSION['email']; 
            ?>
            </li>         
            <li><h1> | </h1></li>
            <li><h1><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <style="float:right"> <a href="logout.php"> LOG OUT </a></h1></li>
            <?php  
            }
            else
            {
            ?>
            <li><h1><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <style="float:right" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"> LOG IN </h1></li>
            <li><h1> | </h1></li>
            <li><h1><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <style="float:right" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'"> REGISTER </h1></li>       
            <?php  
            } 
            ?>              
        </ul>
    </div>    
    </div>    
</header>
```

the contents of logout.php is as given below

```
<?php
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location:index.php');
```

?>

Comment: What happens when you click on the log out button. Does it just do nothing?

Comment: you mean a plain HTML link doesn't work ? <a href="logout.php"> LOG OUT </a> ? pages are in the same folder ? any include that would mess the whole thing ?

Comment: Turn on your error reporting of PHP and see what you get when you click logout.php and If logout.php is not reachable you get 404 but what if something wrong in logout.php file. So to see if something wrong in your logout.php file please turn on your error reporting. There are different methods to do that.

Comment: so what does logout.php has in it?

Comment: Despite the path location of logout being correct, the button does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line to your logout.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location:index.php');
?>
```

Destroying the session will delete all session data so the `session_unset()` line is unnecessary.